# Laravel returns Patchwork\\utf8\\Bootup error

Tags: php, ubuntu, utf-8, laravel, composer-php

I have a problem in my laravel 4.1 project. I am executing it on Ubuntu 14.04. I copied the running instance of project from another Ubuntu OS. When I refresh the page on virtual host, I get a blank page. And apache access logs return 500 error and error logs return the following error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Patchwork\\Utf8\\Bootup' not found in /var/www/www.domain.com/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46
```

What is wrong in here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `composer update` or `composer install` -- you're missing the vendor packages.